# Should I call all methods from one main method, or call next method at the end of current?

Tags: java, methods, coding-style, code-cleanup

If I call method `makeDinner()`, and this method has submethods `prepareTomatoes()` and `prepareMeat()`, should I

a) call them both from `makeDinner()` or

b) call `prepareTomatoes()` and at the end of that method, call `prepareMeat()`?

Is there any general approach to this? I have some problems in general with splitting code to different methods and deciding what still belongs to that method and what doesn't.

edit: This was bad example, it really is very situational as I see.
My specific case was that I had to do 3 tasks - paint the health bar according to health, call `died()` if `health == 0.0f`, and finally draw the health bar.
I spread it into 3 methods - I called `drawHealthBar()` - inside this method I called `paintHealthBar()` - and inside this method, I'm calling `died()` (if `health == 0.0f` of course).

Now, you could expect that if you call `drawHealthBar()` the method also checks the health and draws the health bar in a specific color. But I am afraid that if I am going to call `died()` from `paintHealthBar()`, it will confuse someone else looking at the code or even me 6 months later.

This can get a lot more complex than that, but even in that "simple" case I don't know if I should call `paintHealthBar()`, then `drawHealthBar()`, then `checkDeath()` all from the "main" method, or if it's alright to call it the way I did it (descendingly), or if calling `draw()` and inside this method `paint()` is alright, but I should call `checkDeath()` from main method?

Comment: Could you provide a complete example rather than describing it? While I *think* I know what you mean, it would be much easier to avoid ambiguity if you presented the alternatives clearly. It sounds very wrong for `prepareTomatoes` to call `prepareMeat` though - that's not what it says it's going to do. What if I want tomatoes but not meat?

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a bad example. I edited my answer and I hope it's clear now. @ParkerHalo

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you want to have good readability in your code so this is a really situation based question. In your specific example, my personal opinion would be to have the prepareTomatoes and prepareMeat methods INSIDE the makeDinner method.

However, this is very generalized because what if you need to prepare the meat, during the time the tomatoes are cooking? It then depends whether you'll ALWAYS prepare the meat during the time you prepare the tomatoes and so forth... It's really situational.

There's not really a rule, telling you to do this or that. You generally get a feeling for it. You generally want your methods to water down to as specific as possible, so you could split up your makeTomatoes into "cutTomatoes", "cleanTomatoes", "cookTomatoes",...

But if you go too far in splitting, you'll lose out on readability again.

Answer (score 0):

[Demeter´s law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) states that you should not talk with strangers, this means that chained call like `car.getEngine().turnOn()` should be avoided and `carg.turnOn()` is preferable. Now let suppose you have a business logic to now allow turn the engine on when the car has no fuel and emit an alert to the driver:

```
if (car.hasFuel()){
  car.getEngine().turnOn();
}else{
  car.alertDriver();
}
```

It´s preferable to have this logic encapsulated into a `cart.turnOn()` method rather than outside the car. You can better create a unit test and avoid the mistake of turn on the car without check the business rules. [Simplify method calls](https://refactoring.guru/refactoring/techniques/simplifying-method-calls) improve the readability of your code.